# Incompatible types error when creating dialog

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, joptionpane

I'm trying to create an input dialog, using a static method of JOptionPane:

```
public static Object showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType,
                                     Icon icon,
                                     Object[] selectionValues,
                                     Object initialSelectionValue)
                              throws HeadlessException
```

My code is as follows:

```
String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                              "Username", 
                                              "Pick a name",    
                                              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                              null, 
                                              null, 
                                              "default_name");
```

This gets me the error:

```
ChatController.java:49: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String
```

There must be something simple I'm missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns an object, [as specified in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29), but you're expecting a String. Note that the selection options

```
 Object[] selectionValues
```

is an array of `Objects`, so you'll get one of those objects back. There's nothing to say they're specified as strings. If the values *are* strings, then you can/should cast appropriately.

Note also you're passing a null array. From the doc:

> The user will able to choose from selectionValues, where null implies
>   the user can input whatever they wish

Answer (score 1):

```
String username =(String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                          "Username", 
                                          "Pick a name",    
                                          JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                          null, 
                                          null, 
                                          "default_name");
```

maybe this will solve it

Comment: Thanks, I realized the issue as soon as I posted this :P